# Xamarin.Android app "READ_CONTACTS" permission always added automatically

Tags: android, xamarin, permissions, xamarin.android

My problem is that I do not want to set a privacy policy for my app, I would rather remove all of the unnecessary permission requests.

I have removed the "READ_CONTACTS" permission from my AndroidManifest.xml, but when trying to upload to Play Store, it always says:

> The apk has permissions that require a privacy policy set for the app, e.g: android.permission.READ_CONTACTS. [403]

It seems to me, that "READ_CONTACTS" permission is always added automatically.
Is there a way to remove this?

I only use the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Are you including any 3rd-party libraries that are adding the contacts permission? Review the final manifest that is included into your apk (in the obj bin directory) or unzip your apk and review it there.

Comment: Yes, I use SignaturePad.Android, RestSharp, Newtonsoft.Json, but I don't think any of these should add the READ_CONTACTS permission. Or at least I have not found anything regarding to that. But the final manifest contains additional permissions.

Comment: If the final manifest contains that permission, then it is coming from a 3rd-party source ***if*** you are not defining it in your manifest manually or via an `Attribute` within one of your source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was definitely a 3rd-party library issue.